# Laptop Windows Recovery Hot Key

Tags: windows-vista, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude E6400 laptop that I need to boot to the recovery area to try to reset or reformat. For some reason I cannot get the options to pop up as me what to do next and I do not have the Windows disc.

Questions

1. What key buttons or combinations should I try for further options?
2. What options are available to me if there are no further options?

I basically want to go into the recovery area and then just do a factory reset to all the defaults if possible. I do not want to repair and I do not care about any data on this thing either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the below helps you any, the resource URL is at the bottom.

> Turn on the computer and tap the "F8" key several times to load the
>   "Vista Advanced Boot Options" menu.
>
> Click or use your keyboard's directional keys to select "Repair Your
>   Computer." Press "ENTER" to open the "System Recovery Options" window.
>
> Select the appropriate keyboard layout for your Dell Latitude E6400
>   laptop computer. Click "Next."
>
> Click "Dell Factory Tools," then "Dell Factory Image Restore." Click
>   "Next."
>
> Click "Confirm Data Deletion" to proceed with the system recovery
>   process. After clicking "Confirm Data Deletion," you will no longer be
>   able to backup data (images, movies, document, etc.) files from the
>   computer and the partition will be formatted. Ensure that you have
>   backed up your system data onto another computer or removable media
>   device before proceeding. The recovery process will take approximately
>   five minutes.
>
> Click "Finish" to restart the computer. Allow the operating system to
>   boot up completely, which completes the recovery process for your Dell
>   Latitude E6400 laptop computer.

**RESOURCE:** *http://www.ehow.com/how_8005941_recover-latitude-e6400.html*